# mysql query in codeigniter returns nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
SELECT * 
FROM fx_dirprocess 
WHERE `pro_id` IN (SELECT MAX(`pro_id`) FROM fx_dirprocess GROUP BY name) 
  AND `co_id`=$company;
```

How to construct this query in codeigniter

Following I have tried and no use:

## first option

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('fx_dirprocess');
$this->db->where('`pro_id` IN (SELECT MAX(`pro_id`) 
                               FROM `fx_dirprocess`  
                               GROUP BY `name`,’co_id’,$company)’, NULL, FALSE);
```

## second option

```
$this->db->select_max(‘pro_id’)->group_by(‘name’);
$where_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select('fx_dirprocess');


$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('fx_dirprocess');
$this->db->where("`pro_id`  IN ($where_clause)", NULL, co_id,$company);
```

Comment: your sql query was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `GROUP BY` for selecting `MAX` value, it won't give exact value. you like following

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `fx_dirprocess` WHERE `pro_id` IN (SELECT MAX(`pro_id`) FROM `fx_dirprocess`) AND `co_id` = '{$company}'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql_query);
return ($query->num_rows() > 1) ? $query->row() : $query->result();
```

Comment: This query is returning only one result...I want the max of every group..so i did group by name

Comment: okay then add like this inside bracket
(SELECT MAX(`pro_id`) FROM `fx_dirprocess` GROUP BY `name`)

Answer (score 0):

in order to get protected by the Querybuilder of CI you can do this by using `get_compiled_select`

the following should work

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('fx_dirprocess')
    ->where('pro_id IN ('.$this->db->select_max('pro_id')->from('fx_dirprocess')->group_by('name')->get_compiled_select().')', NULL, false)
    ->where('co_id', $company)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tejaswini please check the below code hope it will help.

```
// make A subquery :-
$this->db->select_max('pro_id')->from('fx_dirprocess')->group_by('name');
$subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

// Now the main query is :-
$this->db->select('*')->from('fx_dirprocess');
$this->db->where("pro_id IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->get()->result();
```

Thanks!